# Regex which will match all words in string

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Can you please suggest a regex code that will select all words. Basically everything between whitespaces

Example-string(`'This is a man's world'`)
I need to match-`'This' 'is' 'a' 'man\s' 'world'`

Comment: Why does the apostrophe get replaced by a backslash in the output?  Did you mean to escape it?  Do you expect the regex to do that too? Basically, you want: `\w+`

Comment: `\S+` will match all non-whitespace characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one should do:

```
(\S+)
```

It will match all sequences of non-space characters.

See https://regex101.com/r/LZ6C1s/2 for explanation